# Batch File to zip files - apply to sub directories

Tags: batch-file, zip

I'm looking to get a batch file to apply to all sub directories.

I have a number of folders. Each folder will contain file pairs
xxx1.mp3 and xxx1.cdg,
xxx2.mp3 and xxx2.cdg,
etc.

I have a 7zip batch file that will look for file pairs and create a single zip file xxx1.zip, xxx2.zip and delete the (now) redundant cdg/mp3 files.

However, this will only work if the bat file is run in each individual folder. What I'm really looking for is a switch to add to the bat file that if I run in the root directory, will run through all sub directories also.

The code I currently run is:

```
FOR  %F IN (*.cdg) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7Z.exe" a "%~nF.zip" "%~nF.cdg" "%~nF.mp3" -sdel
```

Any help?

Comment: Looping (iterating) through directories in a batch file has been asked and answered here several times before. Do some searching and you should turn up some code that will get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FOR /R %%F IN (*.cdg) DO IF EXIST "%%~dpnF.mp3" pushd "%%~dpF"&ECHO("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7Z.exe" a "%%~nF.zip" "%%~nF.cdg" "%%~nF.mp3" -sdel&POPD
```

Note that this is a **batch** line - to execute from the prompt, reduce each `%%` in metavariable to `%` (but it's a whole lot easier to put it into a batch by cut-and-paste;saves all those typos...)

The required commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, delete the string `ECHO(` which appears before your command to actually execute the commands.

Using `for /r` will iterate through the filenames matching the supplied mask (it's possible to also add a starting directory - see `for /?|more` from the prompt.)

Since we know the selected full filename exists, first check that the paired file exists, then switch to the required directory, archive, and switch back.